# How do I "straighten" the latex out?

Tags: lyx, indentation

The picture seen below is essentially what happens to me when I compile 1 long line of latex inside a latex box in LyX- it "clusters" up on top of the original line instead of spreading out to a new line.... How do I fix this?

[image]

Also, how can I organize my work such that each equation is written on a new line? I'm aware that ctrl+shift+M is able to do that, but I want my work not to be in large text nor centered. Creating a new line doesn't work in my case as there'll be the indentation from enumerate.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Exercise 16:
\global\long\def\and{\wedge}%
\global\long\def\or{\vee}%
\begin{enumerate}
\item $[(p\implies q)\and(q\implies r)]\implies(p\implies r)\equiv\neg[(\neg p\or q)\and(\neg q\or r)]\or(\neg q\or r)\equiv\neg(\neg p\or q)\or\neg(\neg q\or r)\or(\neg p\or r)\equiv(p\and\neg q)\or(q\and\neg r)\or\neg q\or r\equiv[(\neg q\and p)\or\neg q]\or[(q\and\neg r)\or r]\equiv\neg q\or p\or q\or r$As
one can easily observe, $\neg q\or q$ is a tautology, hence the entire
statement is a tautology.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without show the lyx file, nor the latex export, with these clues is hard to guess what are you doing really.  Take your time to understand the importance add to the questions of this site a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/8VtVXjU) I hope this clears things up. I enumerated this long line of latex code, which "wraps up" into a chunk, as you can see in the post, rather than spread out to another line. How do I fix that? Or am I still too vague?

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot of Lyx window is not enough. Moreover, external links tends to break time making the question more unclear for future readers.  Reduce your lyx document to just the part (minimal) showing the problem (example).  Check that is still compilable (working)  with Ctrl+R,  and edit the question to paste also the screenshot of the pdf result, not only of the LyX editor. Finally, **and more important**,  go to `View` → `Code preview Pane`, check that  at the right  that is selected show the  `Complete source`, copy that code, and paste it all in the question.

Comment: Alright. Did I do it right this time? .... actually, I messed up the adding of the images...

Comment: (1) Do not paste the latex code as image,  but as plain text, then use `{}` icon to format it. The idea is make it available to us, so we can copy it,  and then reproduce exactly the problem in our computers (2) As said before, for this we need the complete source, not a chunk of code. A longer list with more longer items does not help. What help is a  **complete** code, i.e.,  from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`  with a miminal content, always checking that document reduction maintain the problem, without cange it or add another new.

Comment: Welcome. // This place has a simple currency: code, which compiles AND shows your problem. No code, almost no answer, because most here don't spend time on speculations.

Comment: Note that a LyX file is a text file, it would really help if you will open the file with a text editor and copy the content to your post.

Comment: How do I extract the latex code, though? I'm not seeing the `\documentclass` and `\end{document}` from the code preview pane, even with complete source

Comment: With your last comment I am afraid that you have installed LyX but not a TeX distribution, so `Format:`, in right upper coin of the Cone Preview Pane, allow you to view the export to plain text format or LyxHTML, but not the LaTeX formats (you should see 5 more formats here). When you have TeX, the default format is "LaTeX (pdflatex)" so if you type "foo" in bold in the edit window, you must see `\textbf{foo}` in the Code Preview Pane. Also the `Tools` menu must say that you some TeX paraphernalia in your hard disk.

Comment: Ah, got it, updated accordingly. Hope I did it right this time